# How to add tab index of selectOneChoice of Oracle's ADF?

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, oracle-adf

How to add tab index of selectOneChoice of Oracle's ADF ?

Comment: you want to set the tab index OF a selectOneChoice, or you want to use tab within the component?

Comment: I simply trying to add the tab index of a selectOneChoice. Thanks a lot in advance for helping me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot control it at standard JSF level. At least, not with the standard components and renderers. The specified `tabindex` will be applied on **all** generated elements (I don't to ADF, but I guess that it are the radio buttons).

You could consider to override the renderer associated with the `af:selectOneChoice` so that it takes an addidional attribute `tabindexes` or so accepting a commaseparated string of indexes and applies them on the generated radiobuttons subsequently.

You need to consult the ADF documentation of the component in question to find out which component family it belongs and which renderer it is using. Once found out, you basically need to create a class which `extends` it and overrides the `renderOption()` method (at least, it is called with exactly that name in the JSF standard `com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.RadioRenderer` class). You basically need to copy the method logic (not sure about ADF, but basic JSF implementations are open source) and add the following logic to it:

```
String tabindexes = (String) component.getAttributes().get("tabindexes");
if (tabindexes != null) {
    String[] tabindexItems = tabindexes.split("\\s*,\\s*");
    String indexKey = component.getClientId(context) + "_currentTabIndex";
    Integer index = (Integer) component.getAttributes().get(indexKey);
    if (index == null || index == tabindexItems.length) {
        index = 0; // Note this thus restarts at 0 if there are more selectitems than tabindexes. Just to be on the safe side.
    }
    String tabindex = tabindexItems[index];
    component.getAttributes().put(indexKey, ++index); // We need to save it for the next generated input element.
    writer.writeAttribute("tabindex", tabindex, "tabindex");
}
```

If you declare the custom renderer in `faces-config.xml` as follows

```
<render-kit>
    <renderer>
        <component-family>put here the component family of af:selectOneChoice</component-family>
        <renderer-type>put here the renderer type of af:selectOneChoice</renderer-type>
        <renderer-class>com.example.YourCustomRadioRenderer</renderer-class>
    </renderer>
</render-kit>
```

then you can use the extra `tabindexes` attribute as follows:

```
<af:selectOneChoice .... >
    <f:attribute name="tabindexes" value="1,3,5,7,2,4,6,8" />
```

You can even put some EL in it so that you can obtain it as a (generated) string from the bean property.

```
<af:selectOneChoice .... >
    <f:attribute name="tabindexes" value="#{bean.tabindexes}" />
```

Hope this gives new insights.